# Which permissions required for get post's likes in Facebook API (Granularity-daily)?

Tags: api, rest, facebook

I have this permissions:ads_read,read_insights,ads_management,pages_manage_ads, pages_manage_posts

but this API call doesn't work: post-id/comments

Documentation- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/comments/

I get an error:

```
{
 "error": {
   "message": "(#200) Missing Permissions",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 200,
   "fbtrace_id": "AHxXdSj4NLHi7WVKhRYQWV2"
 }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Should be [`pages_read_user_content`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/pages_read_user_content), I think.

Comment: @CBroe I had it as well, the same error.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/#readperms lists several requirements, check those.

Comment: @CBroe you are correct. it's working, Thanks. (the permission as you said )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
pages_read_user_content permission as needed.

Thanks to @CBroe